# How to put a cellphone keyboard below a fixed footer JqueryMobile

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a problem in my web application in the chat part with jQuery Mobile and cordova.
I decided to fixed the footer with an textaera and a button to send message. But when I touch the textarea to write a message my keybord doesn't show up. I guess it is hide :S

Any idea to fixe that?

Here is my code:

```
<div data-role="content" class="bg">
    <div class="chat-liste">
        <div class="chat-left">
        </div>
        <div class="chat-content">
        </div>
        <div class="chat-form" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <textarea class="chat-form-text"></textarea><input type="submit" class="chat-form-submit send"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: can you show the code pls ?

Comment: <div data-role="content" class="bg">
   <div class="chat-liste">
   <div class="chat-left"></div>
   <div class="chat-content"></div>
   <div class="chat-form" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <textarea class="chat-form-text"></textarea>
    
    <input type="submit" class="chat-form-submit send"/>
   </div>
  </div></div>

Answer (score 0):

Actually the keyboard is not html but a part of the system widgets so it's impossible to hide it behind a html element.

Be sure that no other invisible elements above the textarea are recieving / stealing it's  touch event. Prerequisite is that your textarea can be touched.

Would need to see your css and code too to tell if it's a html problem or there is somewhere in your jq an **event.preventDefault()** on this element.

When it's html-problem. Try to give the textarea a higher z-index like this:

```
<textarea class="chat-form-text" style="z-index:10000;"></textarea>
```